# Dozer - Mapping Collections

Tags: java, jaxb, dozer

I have the a scenario that is similar to the following two classes:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Set<Person> familyMembers;
    //constructors & getters and setters
}
```

The `Person` class is my source class. I'm trying to use Dover to map this class to the following target classes:

```
public class PersonPrime {
    private String personName;
    private FamilyMembers familyMembers;
    //constructors & getters and setters
}

public class FamilyMembers {
    private List<PersonPrime> familyMembers;
    //constructors & getters and setters
}
```

The target classes in my actual scenario are generated by JAXB (using XSDs which I have created). The XSDs were prescribed and I can't really change them, therefore the target classes cannot be changed. I currently am able to map the primitives in my mappings XML file but I cannot maps the collection.

Any idea how I can use Dozer to map an object of `Person` to an object of type `PersonPrime`?

Comment: IMHO you will need to use Custom convertors http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html

Answer (score 2):

By default JaxB does not generate setters for the collections within the "FamilyMembers" type. This will result in a null pointer exeception deep within the guts of Dozer (org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.java:323 in Dozer 5.4.0) when Dozer tries to call the non-existent setter. To avoid this, you need to set is-accessible true on the collection field, which will cause it to set the familyMembers.familyMembers field directly. Thus, the following modified mapping who should work:

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>Person</class-a>
  <class-b>PersonPrime</class-b>
  <field>
    <a>name</a>
    <b>personName</b>
  </field>
  <field>
    <a>familyMembers</a>
    <b is-accessible="true">familyMembers.familyMembers</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, adding `is-accessible="true"` to the JAXB collection side worked as expected. But you might should consider to use the JAXBBeanFactory for the JAXB class as some things could go wrong without it. To do so add `<class-b bean-factory="org.dozer.factory.JAXBBeanFactory">...</class-b>`

Comment: This saved lot of time as i was struggling to assign list from a bean to jaxb list. 

Please see, that JAXB doesn't generate setters for Lists so is-accessible is the only savior.

My example: List from <a> to List <b>
<field>
            <a>lmsVAcctDtlsLLRec</a>
            <b is-accessible="true">body.vAcctDtlsAddRequest.vAcctDtlsAddRq.lmsVAcctDtlsLLRec</b>
        </field>

Answer (score 0):

The following mapping works.

`<mapping>
    <class-a>Person</class-a>
    <class-b>PersonPrime</class-b>
    <field>
      <a>name</a>
      <b>personName</b>
    </field>
    <field>
      <a>familyMembers</a>
      <b>familyMembers.familyMembers</b>
    </field>
  </mapping>`